# SharePoint Master Page File Not Found error

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

When I create master page for my web application. after deployed the solution the site showing "Fine Not Found" error.. This is What i have done to create the master page. 1. Created web application in SPCA, 2. In Visual studio i added module and rename the sample.txt to customname.master, 3. Then i copied all code from V4 file paste into my customname.master file. 4. Changes in Element.xml is

```
          <Module Name="MobileSales" List="116" Url="_catalogs/masterpage">
          <File Path="MobileSales\MobileSales.master" Url="MobileSales/MobileSales.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="FALSE"/>
          </Module>
```

1. Changes in Feature is

   ```
     public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
      {
       //SPSite curSite = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
       //SPWeb curWeb = curSite.RootWeb;
       SPWeb curWeb = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;
       Uri masterUri = new Uri(curWeb.Url +   "/_catalogs/masterpage/MobileSales.master");
       curWeb.MasterUrl = masterUri.AbsolutePath;
       curWeb.CustomMasterUrl = masterUri.AbsolutePath;
       curWeb.Update();
   }
   ```
2. Deployed the solution.

Then i got the error "file not found..  Please help.. i am new to SP.. Please tell me how to  create master page in SharePoint 2010 with out using SharePoint Designer. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There might be multiple causes for this error, here are some to check:

- Make sure you published the master page
- Make sure to take into account the actual Managed path - "/" vs. deeper managed path, e.g. "/sites/" and construct it accordingly when you change the master page programatically.
- do make sure it your master page is actually physically deployed in the _catalogs/masterpage document library - seems like in your code, but ensure this via SharePoint 2010 Designer to validate
- in your code, make sure that SPWeb retrieved from Parent is actually not null (i assume here your feature is site collection scoped - if not please do change as such)
- I fear your feature states to deploy it physically in a sub-folder called "MobileSales" where as your code to change the master page is actually loading from root of the master page library. - i also suspect this to be the culprit

Answer (score 1):

Check out that:
The property "Url" of the elements.xml is pointing to "MobileSales/MobileSales.master".

```
 <Module Name="MobileSales" List="116" Url="_catalogs/masterpage">
      <File Path="MobileSales\MobileSales.master" Url="MobileSales/MobileSales.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="FALSE"/>
      </Module>
```

So when activated, there will be a "MobileSales" folder on your _catalog/masterpage/ library.

On your code, your target is "/_catalogs/masterpage/MobileSales.master".

You should replace one or another.

Cheers.

Comment: This is certainly the problem, good catch :)